# hasClass not read class adds per event

Tags: jquery

I'm trying the following to identify the added after the scroll event class, but does not work, anyone know why?

```
// works
$(window).scroll( function(){
    $('#header .sticky').addClass('test');
});

// not work
if ($('#header .sticky').hasClass("test")) {
    alert('worksssssssss');
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zs659xgq/)

Comment: What do you expect? The `scroll` handler is executed on `scroll` event and the `if` statement is executed just once.

Comment: XYQuestion? What are you actually trying to accomplish? You should explain what you're after, I'm sure there are far better solutions to the actual problem.

Comment: First part just registers your function as an Event Handler for`scroll`  Your second part is exacted immediately after and way before a `scroll` event is actually triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $sticky = $('#header .sticky'); // Cache your elements

function testMyClass() {            // Wrap in function
    if ($sticky.hasClass("test")) {
        alert('worksssssssss');
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $sticky.addClass('test');
    testMyClass();                 // And call your fn wherever you want.
});
```

Not sure what you're after, the above will yield "workssssss" annoyingly often.
Also note that the scroll event is pretty expensive to add all over again a class to a a DOM element or test if a *class* element has a class. You might want to use `.one("scroll", function)` method or add a flag.